# How to implement SSL when accessing server through ip address?

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, xampp

I am accessing my server in my phone through the ip address of the server (ex. http://13.70.72.102:7777/test/index.php) the ip address (13.70.72.102) is the public address of my server. When I change the http into a https I am getting a "This site can’t provide a secure connection (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)". I can add a SSL to my virtual host but to access my virtual host I need to edit all the host file in each of my device that is why I am accessing my server through my ip address. How can I add a SSL to this?

Here is my host file:

```
127.0.0.1       server.test
13.70.72.102    server.test
```

Here is my httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:7777>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
  ServerName server.test
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName server.test
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/server.test/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/server.test/server.key"
     <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where is that hosts file located?

Comment: @DusanBajic in the server I am trying to access my website through my phone

Comment: That needs to be on the client side (only the second line), that is how client will know what is the ip address of server.test

Comment: @DusanBajic Oh ok, this is how I access my website in my phone http://192.168.120.1/dashboard when I tried to change http to https I have an error "This site can't provide a secure connection". Is there a way to implement ssl here?

Comment: Is server.test really the hostname you are using or you just changed it here to hide real name?

Comment: @DusanBajic I changed it to hide the real name

Comment: Well, unless you want to modify hosts file on each client, you will need a DNS server for your domain name, and there you will point your hostname to desired ip address

Comment: @DusanBajic Is there a way to implement ssl on 192.168.120.1/dashboard instead?

Comment: What exactly happpens now if you try to access that url  with https://

Comment: @DusanBajic I am getting "This site can't provide a secure connection"

Comment: Hm, and if you try from desktop browser?

Comment: @DusanBajic Still the same result